# I want rank using some condition

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to rank using total number and some conditions like exam_Id, class_id,section_id, year. I have many data using different exam_Id,class_id,section_id, year. Now I want to rank them when these items(exam_Id,class_id,section_id,year) match.
In the below, I gave you a sql query where I tried something but it was giving the whole result.

```
SELECT id, student_id, total_mark, FIND_IN_SET( total_mark, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total_mark
ORDER BY total_mark DESC ) 
FROM total_marks )
) AS rank
FROM total_marks
```

[SQL fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609627/1/0)

Comment: can you please create a SQL fiddle or post a table data so that community can have a better understanding

Comment: i dont know how create SQL fiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com please check this site or post table data and desire result

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609627/1/0

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would help explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rank -- using this method -- for groups of records, then you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id, student_id, exam_id, class_id, total_mark, section_id, year,
       FIND_IN_SET(total_mark,
                   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total_mark ORDER BY total_mark DESC ) 
                     FROM total_marks tm2
                     WHERE tm2.exam_Id = tm.exam_id AND
                           tm2.class_id = tm.class_id AND
                           tm2.section_id = tm.section_id AND
                           tm2.year = tm.year
                   )
                  ) AS rank
FROM total_marks tm;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609627/19) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that the right way to write this uses window functions:

```
SELECT tm.*,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY exam_Id, class_id, section_id, year 
                    ORDER BY total_mark DESC
                   ) as rank
FROM total_marks tm;
```

This function is standard SQL and available in MYSQL since version 8.0.